# Facebook Graph API Explorer "Results Export" out?

Tags: json, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

- Is there any way to export the results out of [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) please?
- Or is there any external api to interact directly with it?

Comment: Why you need export result from Facebook Graph API Explorer?

Comment: Because i won't need to write the app, to get data. Its totally nonsense, to write app, since i have data over there easily.

Comment: No, Facebook Graph API Explorer is only for testing purpose, you should manage your own application. Register app is very easy to do on https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: No, Facebook Graph API can even query friends objects, lets say `statuses`. Can APP do it straight? (when i query from app, it returns blanksss... so obviously the Explorer is better)

Comment: I dont' understand, you should know Graph API is an app also, the app details is here: http://graph.facebook.com/145634995501895. You cannot get app access token for Graph API because you doesn't have API SECRET key, so the functionalities is limited compare with your own app. Moreover, grant another user using app except your app is violate TOS of facebook platform.

Comment: 'blank' is because you doesn't granted certain permissions or other factor such as disable migration on https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/advanced.

Comment: Lets say i can query `statuses` of my friendssssss, via Graph API Explorer. But such query is returning blank! in the own App. Lets say: `SELECT message,uid,time FROM status WHERE uid='6706XXXXX'`. GET DATA via Graph API Explorer, NOT GETTING via own App Code.

Comment: No, if you click "Clear" all the permission on 'Get access token' button on Graph API Explorer. You would get blank result too. Because you require "friends_status" permission. You can granted "friends_status" permission with your registered app if you want to.

Comment: This permission needs to be "requested" from the friend/user, right???

Comment: Yes, the target user have to go through login process and authentication process to get "User Access Token". Example is https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=145634995501895&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?display=page&response_type=token&fbconnect=1&perms=manage_pages,status_update,friends_status

Comment: So when i use Graph API Explorer, i do not need to do this dumb "permission request" thing, from the target user (my friend or my girl friend). I can straight away get his/her data. You get it?

Comment: No, you still need to grant permission. You can test the step: Remove Graph API explorer on https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications. then you visit https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fhome, there's no default access token here. Or you create a new account, then you visit graph api explorer, there's no default access token here. The security mentions is improved, there's no automatically granted permission by now.

Comment: But why should i remove/clear it? My point here is "IF YOU ARE MY FRIEND, I `DO ""NOT"" NEED` TO ASK PERMISSION `FROM YOU` TO GET YOUR DATA" ..if i use Graph API Explorer. But if i make the same way from APP, i will need your permission accepted. Got it?

Comment: No, if you want to get statuses(exclude private status) from your friends, you grant permission for "friends_status" from your apps, it's not require your friend to accept it, just you. What i explain just now is get private statuses of your friend.

Comment: Then why my app/code is returning blanks `Array( )` to me??? >.<

Comment: Try this https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=145634995501895&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?display=page&response_type=token&fbconnect=1&perms=manage_pages,status_update,friends_status, replace the 145634995501895 to your app_id. You should able to capture access token on the final redirected url. Use this access token to request https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20message%2C%20uid%2C%20time%20FROM%20status%20WHERE%20uid%3D'6706XXXXX'&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: Hi!!! Can you also help me with this please :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296799/facebook-app-to-remove-previous-access-tokens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Graph API Explorer is just a frontend to the Graph API. If you need to do it once, just copy-paste the JSON data to a new file and then manipulate that.

If you need to script it, you can do it in a few lines of PHP:

```
<?php 

$data = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola");
file_put_contents("cocacola.json",$data);
print_r( json_decode($data, true) );
```

Comment: hi thanks for your help. But as you will also know, manual copy/paste is not that easy when you get the huge amount of data returning. Because the pages will be broken in to next pages. Not all in one page. ___ For the `code` logic above, is it `graph.facebook....`? Isn't it `developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer`? Sorry for my dummy questions as this is my very first try on FB app development.

Comment: SUPER COOOL!!! buddy! Thanks!! Now i can use `/<mygirl's-uid>/statuses` ^^