# Facebook App: How to Remove (or) make expired the previous used Access Tokens?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, access-token

I accidentally gave/passed the `Access Token` (The one i generated from Graph API Explorer) to my friend.

Because while i was doing App Development for my Demo-App, i accidentally passed the testing url like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=XXXXose0cBAJdNvsidbmeGE0cFaqv67nBxNuPjFh2y1E0f8J93K1IlCBYDW49LCfein6hkZBZCKIUmZCTACeovVcVrorrVhP2BScUIujD5Y1wT232ceXXXXXXXXX
```

.. which URL contained the `access_token` inside.

- How to make it expired/useless please?

Comment: Was it an app access token or a user one?

Comment: The one i generated from `Graph API Explorer`. It is APP Token, right? (Please see my edited question again above) Thanks!!

Comment: it was probably a user one for a specific app. I don't think it should be too much of an issue, as the token should be tied to your account and app. Sounds to me like you don't really trust your friend. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/

Comment: Urgh, its not about trust or anything. Who want to share their access token to others :( Is it no way to make it expired, please?

Comment: If it was a user token it's tied to your account anyway, so it shouldn't work for him

Comment: Negative, impossible you're able to get App access token from Graph API Explorer without APP SECRET. Moreover, the Graph API Explorer only provide you the platform to get User Access Token.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, simply remove the Graph API explorer app at https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications wouldn't expire your access token. Moreover, change your password wouldn't expired the access token(it's weird by now, i'm not sure it should be consider a serious security bug OR by design) !!!

However, you can visit https://www.facebook.com/deactivate.php, then click the radio button of "**This is temporary. I'll be back.**". Then click "Confirm". Then it would ask you current password and so on.

After that, go to https://www.facebook.com/YOUR_USER_ID wouldn't see your profile. Then you just simply login as normal, you would reactive your account. After this, the access token of your previous Graph API explorer would expired.

**Update: You can just change your password and make sure you select 'Log me out of other devices'. It's works fine now(It doesn't works for yesterday)**

[image]